# Why am I getting this MySQL database creation error?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a redhat linux in AWS EC2. I created a few dbs yesterday for an application. Today, I am getting an error in creating a new database.

```
mysql -u root -p
pw: xxx

CREATE testdb;
```

I get an error 1064(42000): You have an error in SQL syntex; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntex to use near 'testdb' at line 1.

I also tried `mysqladmin -u root -p$pwd create testdb;`

It takes the password and throws the same problem.

Root has all permissions.

[image: mysql]

Comment: You probably mean CREATE DATABASE testdb;. Note that your question isn't really on-topic for this site, and you made a number of errors pasting the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is `CREATE DATABASE dbname`.

Comment: Sorry for posting it here. It does not make a difference. I also tried CREATE DATABASE testdb; it throws the same error.

Comment: @mysqlnew Can you update your screenshot with one you log in with root in the interactive mode and run `CREATE DATABASE testdb`? Now your screenshot shows different error numbers for your two commands, and the second error number is not found anywhere

Comment: Thanks. Same outcome. the error is 1006 (HY000) (errno: 15519024).

Comment: Please have a look at questions related to that 1006 error, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719748/error-1006-hy000-cant-create-database-errno-13-mysql-5-6-12; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120771/mysql-create-database-test-error-1006-hy000-cant-create-database-test-e; https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fix-the-MySQL-error-ERROR-1006-HY000-Cant-create-database-test-errno-2

Comment: It sounds like it is related to a file system problem.

Comment: thanks. I will read the links and post. In the mean time, I did change the data dir from the default path. I have made changes towards that effect in mycnf... However, I wonder, if the permission is still denied to the .sock in the default path. I tried changing the permission by using chown -r mysql:mysql /.../. Change ownership operation was not permitted. I will investigate the url and post. thanks again

Answer (score -1):

@bfrguci: Thanks for the links again. The problem was with permissions. Although I edited my.cnf to address the change of datadir, the .sock folder did not change. Mysql was unable to write to the new data dir.

sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /new_dir/data/; worked for me.